# How to do an "or" in chai should

Tags: chai

How do I do an `or` test with `chai.should`?

e.g. something like

```
total.should.equal(4).or.equal(5)
```

or

```
total.should.equal.any(4,5)
```

What's the right syntax?  I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Viewing the [Chai expect / should documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/), there are several ways to do this test.

Note that you can chain using "and" but apparently not "or" - wish they had this functionality.

1. Check whether an object passes a truth test:

**.satisfy(method)**

```
@param{ Function }matcher
@param{ String }message_optional_

Asserts that the target passes a given truth test.
```

Example:

```
expect(1).to.satisfy(function(num) { return num > 0; });
```

In your case, to test an "or" condition:

```
yourVariable.should.satisfy(function (num) {
    if ((num === 4) || (num === 5)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

2. Check whether a number is within a range:

**.within(start, finish)**

```
@param{ Number }startlowerbound inclusive
@param{ Number }finishupperbound inclusive
@param{ String }message_optional_

Asserts that the target is within a range.
```

Example:

```
expect(7).to.be.within(5,10);
```

Comment: that would work - we could also do something like `(num === 4 || num === 5).should.be.true

Comment: I suspect the reasoning for omitting `or` is to not deal with operation precedence in a library designed for readability.

Comment: `expect(variable).satisfy(function(value) { return true; });` worked for me (using `satisfy` in the statement errored out with version `4.2.0` of chai.

Comment: This doesn't tell you, at a glance which of the multiple failing cases, which failed and which succeeded, when all cases fail.

Comment: The thing about actionable assertion/expect failures is that you can run the tests using 'watch', make refactors and fix regressions without breaking your flow to go decipher cryptic tests. This is why 'oneOf' is the better solution, even if it seems less flexible.

Answer (score 52):

Asserts that the target is a member of the given array list. However, it’s often best to assert that the target is equal to its expected value.

```js
expect(1).to.be.oneOf([1, 2, 3]);
expect(1).to.not.be.oneOf([2, 3, 4]);
```

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem to write tests to postman. I solved using the following script:

```js
// delete all products, need token with admin role to complete this operation
pm.test("response is ok and should delete all products", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.satisfy((status) => status === 204 || status === 404);
});
```

Comment: Why not simply `.satisfy((status) => status === 204 || status === 404)`? So you don't need that `if else` construct

Comment: I always prefer the more easy way to understand to me. This is one case where I prefer write more code to be more clear.

Comment: What you wrote is something like this: `if (boolVar) { return true; } else { return false; }`. This can simply be abbreviated by `return boolVar`. Think about it: you are if-checking a boolean expression to then return the exact same value of the checked boolean expression.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, I got your point, It really doesn't make much sense when simplified, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I shared exactly what you need to check.

```
expect(true).to.satisfy(() => {
    if (total == 4 || total == 5) return true;
    else return false;
});
```

Answer (score -5):

Because chai assertions throw error you could use try/catch construction:

```
try {
    total.should.equal(4)
} catch (e) {
    total.should.equal(5)
}
```

example of more difficult case:

```
try {
    expect(result).to.have.nested.property('data.' + options.path, null)
} catch (e) {
    expect(result).to.have.property('data', null)
}
```