# How to check that element has either of classes in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

We search for an invalid element as following:

```js
const invalidClasses = '.invalid, .invalid-default';

getInvalidElement() {
    cy.get(invalidClasses)
};
```

Now I have another function which accepts the element and checks if it has the invalid classes:

```js
isInvalid(selector) {
 return cy.get(selector).should('have.class','invalid');
}
```

How can I check that the element has any of the two classes?

I know I can do

`cy.get(selector).invoke('attr','class').should('match','/invalid/');`

But what if the classes were different?

(Also the conditional testing does not apply to this case, there is no logic whether it's the first of the classes or the second one, we just want more abstract class for reusing)

Comment: Put in a .then statement and look at results with a debugger statement

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Cypress `.should()` wraps chai assertions, so from [how to do an “or” in chai should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096551/4716245)

the following html fragment

```html
<div id="1" class="class1"></div>
<div id="2" class="class2"></div>
<div id="3" class="class1 class2"></div>
<div id="4" class="class3"></div>
```

can be tested like this

```js
it('finds either class1 or class2', () => {

  cy.get('div#1')
    .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
      const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList); 
      return classList.includes('class1') || classList.includes('class2') // passes
    }) 

  cy.get('div#2')
    .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
      const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList); 
      return classList.includes('class1') || classList.includes('class2') // passes
    }) // passes

  cy.get('div#3')
    .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
      const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList); 
      return classList.includes('class1') || classList.includes('class2') // passes
    }) 

  cy.get('div#4')
    .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
      const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList); 
      return classList.includes('class1') || classList.includes('class2') // fails
    }) 

})
```

Notes

- the param to the function is a jquery object, so use `$el[0]` to reference the element
- `$el[0].classList` return a DomTokenList which is *array-like*, so use `Array.from()` to apply the Array method `.includes()` to it.

You can also make things a bit more generic by extracting the function,

```js
it('finds either class1 or class2', () => {

  const hasAtLeastOneClass = (expectedClasses) => {
    return ($el) => {
      const classList = Array.from($el[0].classList); 
      return expectedClasses.some(expectedClass => classList.includes(expectedClass));
    }
  }

  cy.get('div#1').should('satisfy', hasAtLeastOneClass(['class1', 'class2']));  //passes

  cy.get('div#2').should('satisfy', hasAtLeastOneClass(['class1', 'class2']));  //passes

  cy.get('div#3').should('satisfy', hasAtLeastOneClass(['class1', 'class2']));  //passes

  cy.get('div#4').should('satisfy', hasAtLeastOneClass(['class1', 'class2']));  //fails

})
```

Comment: Cypress should do this for us.  `should.have.class` is different than comparing the whole class list.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass decalte ` const divEl = cy.get('div#1')` and pass it into the `hasAtLeastOneClass(expectedClasses, divEl)` funtion like this?

Comment: Good solution, but one sidenote on using `Array.from ... includes`, would't it be easier to simply use `Element.classList.contains`?

Answer (score 31):

I guess it will works for you:

```
cy.get('section')
.should('have.class', 'container')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to check for either of two classes.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress should provides and method which takes previous subject(locator) and you can apply as many as conditions with and method.

```
cy.get('locator')
.should('have.class', 'validClassname')
.and('not.have.class', 'invalidClassname');
```

I hope this will solve your problem... Vote up this answer to reach more people.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the question a bit. I'm looking for a solution which checks that it has at least of the classes. So it would take an array of classes and fail if none of it was present. If at least on of it was present on the element, it would succeed

Comment: I know this did not answer the question - but it really helped me. thank you.