# Is there a `.should()` assertion that takes a `criteria` callback, and passes when `!!criteria(yield) === true `?

Tags: cypress

I use this code to check it `.tml-tag`'s text content is a valid XML element

```js
const isXmlTag = (tagStr: string) =>
  tagStr.startsWith('<') &&
  tagStr.endsWith('>') &&
  getCharacterUseCountInString(tagStr, '<') === 1 &&
  getCharacterUseCountInString(tagStr, '>') === 1

cy.get('.xml-tag')
  .invoke('text')
  .should(text => assert(isXmlTag(text)))
```

But it feels overly complicated - is there a way to use one of the predefined `should` assertions to evaluate if `yield` passes my callback criteria (`isXmlTag`)?

Something like:

```js
cy.get('.xml-tag')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('satisfy', isXmlTag)
```

Comment: You want to do it without isXmlTag func? And document is actually XML not HTML? Can you please show the XML or relevant fragment.

Comment: No - I want to use my `isXmlTag` criteria function, but more directly than in my 1st example - I want something closer to my 2nd example (second example is pseoudo-code, it doesn't actually work). Anything specific to XML is besides my question.

Comment: Ok, but actually `.should('satisfy', isXmlTag)` looks close to functional. Check out the chaijs docs.

Comment: Check out [How to check that element has either of classes in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62023455/16997707)

Answer (score 1):

`satisfy` is a valid [chai matcher](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy) that can take a function, so if you run

```js
cy.get('.xml-tag')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('satisfy', isXmlTag)
```

you should pass the test.

The yielded subject `text` is automatically passed into your function.